# How can I concatenate the arrays in loop ? Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, concatenation

There is a loop;

```
for i = 1:n

X_rotate  = X.*cos(i*increment) - Y.*sin(i*increment);
X_rotateh = X_rotate./cos(deg2rad(helix_angle));
Y_rotate  = X.*sin(i*increment) + Y.*cos(i*increment);

Helix     = [X_rotateh(1:K1) ; Y_rotate(1:K1)];
fileID    = fopen('helix_values.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fileID,'%f %f\n ', Helix);
fclose(fileID);
end
```

***X*** and ***Y*** are row vectors and their size depends on inputs. By the way, the iteration number ***n*** and the size of ***X*** and ***Y*** can be different. As I said, they depend on inputs.

When open the text file, there just exists the values of last iteration for ***X_rotateh*** and ***Y_rotate***. I need to collect the values of ***X_rotateh*** and ***Y_rotate*** from ***first*** value to ***K1 th*** value of both for every iteration. I have tried to use ***cat*** command. It did not give what I want. On the other hand, I usually meet problems which are about length or size of arrays.

***Those values should be in order in text file like;***

```
%for first iteration;

X_rotateh(1) Y_rotate(1)

X_rotateh(2) Y_rotate(2)

.

.

X_rotateh(K1) Y_rotate(K1)

%for second iteration;

X_rotateh(1) Y_rotate(1)

X_rotateh(2) Y_rotate(2)

.

.

X_rotateh(K1) Y_rotate(K1)
%so on..
```

What may I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `fileID    = fopen('helix_values.txt', 'a')` to append data to the file. Also, that `fopen` line probably shouldn't be in the loop

Comment: I moved **fopen** outside. You are right. However, It is still the same @Dan

Comment: But did you try the line of code I suggested. You need to use `'a'` for append, not `'w'` from write which actually overwrites the file.

Comment: Thank You @dan. It worked. However, I used **fopen** inside the loop. Because, I moved it outside the loop and it did not work. I wanted to let you know

Comment: Yes, you also have to take `fclose` out of the loop! open the file, the loop and append to it, then close the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the text file has results from the last iteration. It's probably because you are opening the text file with `'w'` permission. Which writes the new content but also erases the previously stored content in the file. Try using `'a'` permission. This will append new content without erasing previous content.

`fileID    = fopen('helix_values.txt', 'a');`

You can also find more details with `help fopen` command in MATLAB.

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Yes It did solve the problem, lots of thanks. However, I used **fopen** command inside the loop. It did not work when I moved it outside. @Umair47

Comment: It's working now and it would also work with `fopen` outside the loop.
As @Dan suggested, if you want to take `fopen` outside (before the loop starts), you would also have to put `fclose` outside (after the loop ends). In this way, the file would be opened before the loop starts, all the writing would be done inside the loop and after all the iterations are completed, the file would be closed by `fclose`.

Comment: I just want to learn if I use *fopen* inside the loop, is it bad for programming? if it is, why ? @Umair47

Comment: Yes it's better if you keep `fopen` and `fclose` outside. With the current program, the file is 'opened' and 'closed' in every iteration. This is obviously bad for efficiency. In this case, as it is a simple text file, so you wouldn't notice a thing. Otherwise, if it is a large data file, you would start to see the negative effects in the result of a time delay during execution of each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge

Comment: Would you please look at my other question which is related to this question ? @Umair47